# Is there a way to create a UIButton-like frame in iOS without the button?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5, uikit

I'm working on an iPad app right now that takes as input an XML file and outputs a Cocoa-like user interface that's dynamically generated based on the content of the XML file. Part of the specification that I've been given dictates that one of the UI elements is a simple frame that looks exactly like a Cocoa Touch button, but does not act as a button; IE, it does nothing when clicked on, and does not visually change in any way. I wanted to use the iOS equivalent of a NSBox mocked up to look like a NSButton, but upon inspection it seems that there is no UIBox class that is equivalent to a NSBox the same way that UIButton is similar/equivalent to the NSButton. Can anyone more experienced in iOS than I suggest a design pattern for creating a button's 'frame' without the additional weight of a new button?

Comment: Does the frame include text?  If it does, maybe you could just draw the text into an empty image with a button border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, just disable user interaction on the button. This way it will still look like a button but it won't act like one.

```
[myButton setUserInterActionEnabled:NO];
```

Alternatively you could create a `UIImageView` and use Quartz to adjust the corner radius of the image.

```
#import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

[[myImageView layer] setCornerRadius:15.0];
```

Comment: One of the things the NSBox-like needs to have as subviews, though, is  other UIButtons that do have UserInteractionEnabled equal to YES. Fiddling about with the layer seems to be the best bet; do you know how Cocoa Touch in the Interface Builder calculates the cornerRadius of a UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect ?

Comment: @wanderso not sure but it looks like maybe 4-8. Px